# Moodle-Log post data sent by CURL

Tags: logging, curl, moodle

I am trying to post entries on a moodle page using curl, is there a way in which i can log the post entries in some log files

Comment: What web server do you use?

Comment: On linix..i am asking about internal logging by moodle..does it have such provision?

Comment: Yes it has. It logs user activity. Take a look here: http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the add_to_log function eg:

```
 add_to_log($courseid, $module, $action, $url, $info, $coursemodule, $user);
```

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Logging_API